# Created a wordpress page and trying to create a link

Tags: php, wordpress

I had created page in Wordpress at `www.doman.com/vin-number-details/`

I want to pass a URL query string to it like this:

```
www.doman.com/vin-number-details/?name=1FT8W3BTXCEA00153
```

But I am getting page not found. On that page I had copied the PHP code using the **xyz php snippet plugin**.

PHP:

```
<?php
    // example code
    $welcome = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/decodevin/$_GET["name"]?format=json'), true);

    echo "<span style='font-size:16px;color:green;'>Results for: ".'<strong>'.$welcome['SearchCriteria'].'</strong></span><p>&nbsp;</p>';
    if(!empty($welcome)){
        echo '<table class="table"><tbody>';
        foreach($welcome['Results'] as $val){
        echo '<tr><th scope="row" width="30%">'.'#'.$val['VariableId'].'</th><td>'.$val['Variable'].'</td><td>'.$val['Value'].'</td></tr>';
        }
     echo '</tbody></table>';
    }
?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the / before `?name=1FT8W3BTXCEA00153`.

You want to pass a GET request to `www.doman.com/vin-number-details`, the URL you posted is looking for a page called `?name=1FT8W3BTXCEA00153` on `www.doman.com/vin-number-details`.

A bit more about GET here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp